# elasticsearch aggregations on substring

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch, aggregation, analysis

I have a field indexed as String in elasticsearch 5
For example **20090219 , 20100416** etc

I can make a aggregation this data, But I want to aggregate on substring.
that is on
 **2009,2010**

I don't want to convert to date. I want to get first **4 characters** and get the count.
This is my current code.Very new to Elasticsearch

```
$params['body']["aggs"]["Year"]["terms"]["field"] = "PublicationDate.keyword";
$params['body']["aggs"]["Year"]["terms"]["size"]  = 10;
$params['body']["aggs"]["Year"]["terms"]["order"]["_count"] = "desc";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use elasticsearch `script` feature to achieve this.

```
GET my-index/_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "my-agg" : {
            "terms" : {
                "script": {
                  "inline": "doc['PublicationDate.keyword'].getValue().substring(0,4)"
                }, 
                "size": 10, 
                "order" : { "_count" : "desc" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know equivalent `php` script for above command, but believe you will able to make it work in `php`.

Comment: this code gives this error `Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [PublicationDate.keyword] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.`

Comment: Make sure you are using `PublicationDate.keyword` field for aggregations which will have mapping of type `keyword`.

Comment: I did not understand, can you please elaborate

Comment: You need define mapping for `PublicationDate.keyword` as `keyword` type. btw can you share current mapping for `PublicationDate.keyword` field?

Answer (score 1):

this did the task

```
$params['body']["aggs"]["PublicationYear"]["terms"]["script"] = "_value.substring(0,4)";
```